# How do I get the date of last Thursday of the current month in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

How do I get the date of last Thursday of current month in Google Sheets? I am looking to  calculate the number of days from the current date to last Thursday of the current month.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

This formula should work to find the date of the last Thursday of the current month (i.e. current month in this case uses the Today() function to identify what month you are currently in.  If you  have a cell you are keying off of you can replace all the Today()'s with that cell reference)

```
=if(WEEKDAY(EOMONTH(Today(),0),2)=4,EOMONTH(Today(),0),if(Weekday(EOMonth(Today(),0),2)>4,EOMONTH(Today(),0)-WEEKDAY(EOMONTH(Today(),0),2)+4,EOMONTH(Today(),0)-WEEKDAY(EOMONTH(Today(),0),2)-3))
```

Basic principle

- Find the last day of the month
- Figure out what day of the week that is
- adjust to get to the day of the week you want

All the logic (if() statements) are used to determine what to do if the the last day is a Thursday already, and if the weekday of the last day is before or after a Thursday to adjust appropriately.

Since you ultimately want to know how many days from Today() to the last Thursday just add -Today() to the end of that formula.

```
=if(WEEKDAY(EOMONTH(Today(),0),2)=4,EOMONTH(Today(),0),if(Weekday(EOMonth(Today(),0),2)>4,EOMONTH(Today(),0)-WEEKDAY(EOMONTH(Today(),0),2)+4,EOMONTH(Today(),0)-WEEKDAY(EOMONTH(Today(),0),2)-3))-Today()
```

Comment: Really nice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

## Formula

Calculates the last Thursday of the same month as a date. The TODAY function was used in the formula however it could alternatively be a date string, a cell reference, or a formula.

```
=LET(eom,EOMONTH(TODAY(),0), 
     wkd,WEEKDAY(eom), 
     eom+(wkd>4)*7-2-wkd)
```

## Explanation

1. LET is used to store the results of intermediate calculations to reduce code duplication and make the formula easier to read and edit.
2. **`eom`** stores the last day of the same month that contains the date.
3. **`wkd`** stores **`eom`**'s weekday.
4. An offset in days is applied to  **`eom`** to get the last Thursday. To calculate the offset:

   1. If **`wkd>4`**, the offset will be **`5-wkd`**. For example, if the month ends on a Friday, then **`wkd=6`**, and the offset will be **`-1`** because **`5-6=-1`**
   2. Otherwise, if **`NOT(wkd>4)`** the offset will be **`-2-wkd`**. For example, if the month ends on a Tuesday, then **`wkd=3`**, and the offset will be **`-5`** because **`-2-3=-5`**
   3. The approach in the calculation was to simply use **`-2-wkd`** for both cases but add **`7`** whenever **`wkd>4`**:

      ```
      =(wkd>4)*7-2-wkd  // wkd=6
      =(6>4)*7-2-6
      =1*7-2-6
      =-1
      ```

      =(wkd>4)*7-2-wkd  // wkd=3
      =(3>4)*7-2-3
      =0*7-2-3
      =-5